# C++Builder 2007, Union and bit fields

Tags: c++, c++builder, sizeof, unions, bit-fields

Size of this union return 16 bytes (in C++Builder 2007).

```cpp
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned Type:2; 
    unsigned Prev:31;
    unsigned Next:31;
    unsigned SizeInBytes:32;
  };
} eMyUnion;
```

How i must modify this union definition, if i want sizeof(eMyUnion) = 12 bytes ?
(I want keep these fields and its sizes, but it can be reordered).
It is possible ?

Comment: you probably have to set byte alignment. in vs it's with #pragma pack directive, but in c++ builder i don't know

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
  struct
  {
    unsigned Type:2; 
    unsigned Prev:31;
    unsigned Next:31;
    unsigned SizeInBytes:32;
  };
#pragma pack(pop)
```